# Database design for UserConsent

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to create a table where I will be storing if we have user's consent to send emails. Those things can be weeklyEmails, monthylEmails, passwordChangesEmails, profileChangesEmails and so on.

This is what I have thought of making for now:

```
*********************** UserConsent Table ***************************

   |columns|                      |datatype|
    ID                              uuid
    User_id(Foreign_key)            uuid
    weeklyEmails                    boolean
    monthlyEmai                     boolean
    passwordChangeEmails            boolean
```

The downside of this is let's say in the future I want to add another consent like profileChangeEmails or dailyDigestEmails, I will have to write database migrations and add a new column.

Is there a better way to do this where there is no need to create a new column?

It's for a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems adequate.

One thing to think about is whether it is worth it to separate into a 1:1 model like you have specified, rather than just add columns to the user table. If you have a reasonably small user table, it would probably be simpler to add the columns so you don't have to deal with relationship management.

Comment: We have a decent size table and our UserConsent will probably grow as we grow. FreeCodeCamp has done the same way you have mentioned:
https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/blob/master/api-server/common/models/user.json#L106